# Passing params in Rails controller for multiple inputs automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my user edit form I have the following HTML:

```
<p>Name: <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

<p>Email: <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

<% for role in Role.all %>
    <p>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
      <%= role.name %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

So I have `name`, `email` and a bunch of associated `roles`.

Normally in the controller I would do something like:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

and the params being:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

However how do I handle the saving of the roles? And can I just auto-save all the params on the form without having to declare them manually.

I tried this:

```
if @user.update(params)
```

But it didn't work. Is there a way to just save all the params to the correct models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the array in the user_params, and specify that it is an array.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, role_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: That gives me the error: `Role(#70231537324720) expected, got String(#70231444088680)`

Comment: Ah,, yes, sorry, it should've been `role_ids` not `roles`.  Answer edited.  Does that improve?

Comment: Also had to change the `roles` in the view to `role_ids`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use strong parameters if you really don't want to...

`@user.update(params[:user])`

It's highly recommended though. For the sake of security

Comment: That gives me the error: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`